# jquery formatDate localization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, localization, datepicker

I just don't understand, I practically copied the code from `jquery` docs, maybe someone else will see why it is not working.

```
$("#date").text($.datepicker.formatDate('d. MM', new Date()),{monthNames: $.datepicker.regional['lv'].monthNames});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were incorrectly passing the third parameter to `$.datepicker.formatDate()`, in your code it was passed as second parameter to `text()`, the corrected form is as follows:

```
$("#date").text($.datepicker.formatDate('d. MM', new Date(),{monthNames: $.datepicker.regional['lv'].monthNames}));
```